# I seek information about adding SSL to a website

Tags: https

Does anyone have any links or advice about adding SSL to a website?

Comment: Do you want how to configure SSL? or merits/demerits of using SSL?

Comment: I want to learn how to configure it. I guess does it work like an api? or is more of how the sessions are secured?

Comment: Which server? That would be important.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is going to help you.

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation.htm

They work if you want to install the certificate, in other words, that you own the server in which you are hosted, but in sites hosted like in godaddy, etc, you buy the ssl certficate and the installation is done almost automatically from there.

So it depends, but the document from digicert can give you the main idea of the installation in different platforms.

btw- Yes, it is a security protocol only, the "configuration" it's part of the certificate, so the communication is encrypted and that's it.

Marco,

Answer (score 0):

Here you found with diagram; Secure Socket Layer. [How SSL Security Works?](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/)

It is a certificate, you need to configure it on you web server to protect your website.

In case of IIS

First you need to generate a Server Certificate Request to get SSL certificate.

In **IIS Manager** -> **Right click your website** -> **Select Directory Security Tab** -> **Click Server Certificate button** to generate a request.

You need to obtain a certificate from a **Certification Authorities**

More about [SSL and Certificates (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/559bb9d5-0515-4397-83e0-c403c5ed86fe.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

From a programming point of view, you won't notice a lot of difference. The connection between the user's browser and your web server is encrypted, but your code on the web server doesn't have to be concerned about the fact that it's an HTTPS connection. You will still see the same requests and be able to send the same responses, with the web server managing the encryptiong itself.

Having said that, there are sometimes aspects you may be concerned with when programming. For example, there will be a way (depending on your web server) to find out whether a given connection is encrypted or not. You may also want to redirect users to an encrypted or non-encrypted URL as your particular application needs.